# Complex SQL query overloads server - how to simplify

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a complex query which keeps executing forever:

```
SELECT tr.`Fund Name`,
       tr.`Fund ID`
FROM
  (SELECT `Fund Name`,
          `Fund ID`
   FROM (
           (SELECT *
            FROM `trendmetrics`)
         UNION
           (SELECT *
            FROM `trendmetrics_custom`
            WHERE `user_id`=361)) trendmetrics
   WHERE `FactorName`='MSCI in $'
     AND trendmetrics.`Annualmean 2`>0.061
     AND trendmetrics.`VaR 95 2`>-0.04
     AND `Fund ID` IN
       (SELECT `Fund ID`
        FROM (
                (SELECT *
                 FROM `trendmetrics`)
              UNION
                (SELECT *
                 FROM `trendmetrics_custom`
                 WHERE `user_id`=361)) trendmetrics
        WHERE `FactorName`='Oil (Spot West Texas)'
          AND trendmetrics.`Annualmean 1`>0.061
          AND trendmetrics.`VaR 95 1`>-0.04)
     AND `Fund ID` IN
       (SELECT `Fund ID`
        FROM (
                (SELECT *
                 FROM `trendmetrics`)
              UNION
                (SELECT *
                 FROM `trendmetrics_custom`
                 WHERE `user_id`=361)) trendmetrics
        WHERE `FactorName`='Credit Spread (BAA-AAA Moodys)'
          AND trendmetrics.`Annualmean 1`>0.061
          AND trendmetrics.`VaR 95 1`>-0.04)) tr
INNER JOIN (
              (SELECT *
               FROM `quant1`)
            UNION
              (SELECT *
               FROM `quant1_cust`
               WHERE `user_id`=361)) quant1 ON (`tr`.`Fund ID` = `quant1`.`Fund ID`)
```

The problem started after I changed a simple table trendmetrics to a union of two tables:

```
((SELECT * FROM `trendmetrics`) UNION (SELECT * FROM `trendmetrics_custom` WHERE `user_id`=$user_id)) trendmetrics
```

What prevents it from execution? I don't have any errors, but it keeps running until I abort its execution.

UPDATE: the EXPLAIN report:
[image]

Comment: Try putting index on column on USER_ID column

Comment: Run the same query with `EXPLAIN ` in front and paste the result in your question. This will give us the info to give meaningful answers.

Comment: Ok UNIONS are bad / IN statements are bad... SELECT queys without WHERE will also trigger an FULL table scan what is bad... read about joins and indexing...

Comment: type are all is slow,the rows have many rows is slow,you can use index to change the type